# Install Tig with sufficient permissions using `make install`

Tags: permissions, installation, tig

How can I give the command "make install" sufficient permissions to run the following successfully?

```
[~/tig-0.14.1]# make install
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin && \
for prog in tig; do \
    install -p -m 0755 "$prog" "/usr/local/bin"; \
done
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local': Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I run ./configure and make successfully before the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either run `make install` as root, or configure Tig in a directory you have write access to. (Usually with `--prefix=<path>` to the configure command)